# JBox2D collision filtering (categoryBits, maskBits)

Tags: android, box2d, jbox2d

I've read the Box2D manual and I understand how masking works in general. But the results I'm getting are not following what is laid out in the manual.

I have 3 categories of things: players, obstacles and triggers.

players and obstacles collide with each other but not with themselves. I've got this working by setting:

**player**

```
 circleDef.filter.categoryBits = 0x2;
 circleDef.filter.maskBits = 0x4;
```

**obstacle**

```
shapeDef.filter.categoryBits = 0x4;
shapeDef.filter.maskBits = 0x2;
```

I want to also have trigger types... these I'm only using to detect the player and trigger events but should not be collided with by anything. Logically, that should be possible by setting the maskBits to 0x0. The JBox2D collision code is as follows.

**DefaultContactFilter.java**

```
boolean collide = (filter1.maskBits & filter2.categoryBits) != 0 && (filter1.categoryBits & filter2.maskBits) != 0;
return collide;
```

So if the maskBits = 0, then collide should **never** return true. I set the category bits to the next free category - 0x8.

**trigger**

```
shapeDef.filter.categoryBits = 0x8;
shapeDef.filter.maskBits = 0x0;
```

I thought this could be to do with Java's ints working differently to how I expected, but I tested and found the following results:

```
0x2 & 0x2 = 2
0x2 & 0x0 = 0
```

The triggers are meant to be used to trigger events. This is done by implementing the CollisionListener and testing for player collisions with triggers and then setting boolean flags. However, when I run the simulation, the player is colliding with the triggers, and so are the obstacles.

I've also tried setting the category and mask bits to the following respective values:

```
0x0 0x0
0x8 0x8
0x2 0x4
0x4 0x2
```

And the player **always** collides with the trigger object. How do I get the player and obstacles to **never** collide with the trigger object?

Comment: You say "So if the maskBits = 0, then collide should never return true.", but have you tested that?

Comment: Yes, I've tested all the combinations that I list at the bottom.

Comment: I don't know if the fact that I'm running this on an Android phone would make any difference. It's the only thing I can think of. I've also tried setting the player and the trigger's groupIndex to -1, which is supposed to prevent collision.

Comment: Okay, you've tested different inputs, but did you use a log or a debugger to check how the what's the actual value of "collide" on runtime?

Comment: Ok, this question can be removed. Thanks for the help Paolo. I found out that my code was not in fact instantiating the correct physics object. My physics objects are separate from the normal game objects and I was instantiating a game object with the wrong physics object. The masks work as expected and as I explained - but the problem was that a different physics object was interacting behind the scenes for my game object. Very frustrating to find out!